# I am getting error AttributeError: module 'lightblue' has no attribute 'finddevices' in MacOS

Tags: python, macos, module, bluetooth, pybluez

I am using below code on MacOS using python3 :

```
nearby_devices = bluetooth.discover_devices(duration=8,lookup_names=True,flush_cache=True,lookup_class=False)
```

When I run the code , I am getting below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bt_ota.py", line 11, in <module>
    nearby_devices = bluetooth.discover_devices(duration=4,lookup_names=True,flush_cache=True,lookup_class=False)
  File "/Users/kumargaurav/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bluetooth/osx.py", line 12, in discover_devices
    devices = lightblue.finddevices(getnames=lookup_names, length=duration)
AttributeError: module 'lightblue' has no attribute 'finddevices'
```

I have installed python-lightblue using pip install python-lightblue, but still I am getting the error.
Please Help.

Comment: Maybe the `pip` used is for a different version of `python`. Try `python3 -m pip install python-lightblue`

Comment: @Philippe I tried the above command, again landing into same issue.